# Errores al generar APK firmado

Tags: android-studio

Tengo desarrollada una aplicación en la que todo va bien el los emuladores y si genero un `APK` para debug todo funciona perfectamente, pero a la hora de generar un `APK` firmado me da 24 errores con **cannot find symbol variable** como sale en la imagen.

[image: error al generar APK firmado]

Al crear el key store path me sale este mensaje:

> Key was created with errors:
>
> Warning:
> El almacén de claves JKS utiliza un formato propietario. Se recomienda migrar a PKCS12, que es un formato estándar del sector que utiliza "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /media/calero/datos/copia_seguridad_guia_de_viandar/key_store_path_guia_vinadar/GuiadeViandar.jks -destkeystore

He probado ha hacer esto en un terminal (utilizo Ubuntu 18.04):

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /media/calero/datos/copia_seguridad_guia_de_viandar/key_store_path_guia_vinadar/GuiadeViandar.jks -destkeystore GuiadeViandar.p12 -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass wertys2605
>
> Importando el almacén de claves de /media/calero/datos/copia_seguridad_guia_de_viandar/key_store_path_guia_vinadar/GuiadeViandar.jks a GuiadeViandar.p12...
>
> Introduzca la contraseña de almacén de claves de origen:
>
> El alias de entrada existente guiadeviandar ya existe, ¿desea sobrescribirlo? [no]:  si
>
> Introduzca la contraseña de clave para
>
> La entrada del alias guiadeviandar se ha importado correctamente.
>
> Comando de importación completado: 1 entradas importadas correctamente, 0 entradas incorrectas o canceladas

Entiendo que el key ya está correcto, pero no lo tengo muy claro.
Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Cual es la clase ViandarGridView? es importante agregues detalles para poder ayudarte, saludos.

Comment: Hola, el problema es que si no firmo la app todo funciona perfectamente y al firmar da estos errores, no entiendo porque pasa esto, nunca me había pasado.

Comment: Creo que ya he solucionado el problema, no se porqué en el proyecto en android studio en Buiid Variants/Module/app/debug las carpeta res si tenia todos los recursos, pero en release no y he tenido que copiarlos desde debug a release, no se muy bien que es lo que hay que hacer para que se creen en las dos carpetas a la vez. Saludos

Comment: Hola @AntonioCaleroFernandez lo que sucede es que estabas generando tu aplicación siempre con el build variant de "debug", pero ahora que la firmas y quieres generar también el de "release", es importante también agregar sus recursos. Si no hay diferencia entre las apps "debug" y "release" entonces no deberías definir "flavors".

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando "flavors" en tu proyecto, estos regularmente son usados para generar una versión de la aplicación con el mismo código pero diferentes recursos como son gráficos, layouts, menu, assets, etc.

En este caso debes agregar los recursos para los diferentes "flavors", en este caso "debug" y "release", para que al generar las versiones de tu aplicación estas se generen sin problema.

Si solo deseas generar una versión que va a ser firmada, puedes seleccionarla perp es importante que tenga sus propios recursos

Revisa la información relacionada en

[Configurar Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys, ahora entiendo mejor lo que estaba pasando, llevaba un par de años sin programar y trabajos anteriores lo había hecho con Eclipse, pero esta posibilidad de generar diferentes APK con Android Studio me parece muy práctica. Saludos.